# Python list of objects with random attributes

Tags: python, random

(Edit:  randrange is just random.randrange, I didn't write my own RNG)

I'm trying to create a list of instances of a class I defined.  Here's the entire class (by request):

```
from random import randrange

class Poly:
    points = [0] * 8
    fill = 'red'
    alpha = 1.0

    def __init__(self, width=100, height=100):
        for i in range(0, 8, 2):
            self.points[i] = randrange(width)
            self.points[i+1] = randrange(height)
        self.alpha = random()
        return
```

Seems to work fine:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
        Poly().points

[28, 64, 93, 26, 15, 31, 44, 50]
[24, 14, 47, 14, 35, 17, 63, 62]
[99, 28, 90, 29, 56, 59, 57, 33]
[62, 56, 48, 28, 40, 73, 70, 99]
[99, 32, 27, 99, 42, 57, 86, 12]
```

But if I try to create a list of these objects, I get separate instances (different memory addresses) but they all have the same random values:

```
>>> p = []
>>> for i in range(5):
        p.append(Poly())

>>> p
[<gen_image.Poly instance at 0x02D773C8>, <gen_image.Poly instance at 0x02D77FD0>, <gen_image.Poly instance at 0x0321D030>, <gen_image.Poly instance at 0x02D51E40>, <gen_image.Poly instance at 0x02D51DA0>]

>>> for poly in p:
        print poly.points

[75, 18, 5, 76, 6, 64, 95, 54]
[75, 18, 5, 76, 6, 64, 95, 54]
[75, 18, 5, 76, 6, 64, 95, 54]
[75, 18, 5, 76, 6, 64, 95, 54]
[75, 18, 5, 76, 6, 64, 95, 54]
```

What's going on here?  And what's the right way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Write the code for randrange.

Comment: Can you show us full source of the Poly class?

Comment: Okay, but there's really nothing else to see.  Editing original post...

Comment: I see the problem now, I'm writing answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the creation of the array into the `__init__` method.

You're working with a shared array among all objects.

The reason the first shows different is that you print the contents of that array before you construct a new Poly object and thus trample over the array contents. If you had kept them around and inspected them later they would all appear to have the same contents as the last one you generated.

Oh, and try not to simplify code when posting questions. Always post complete, but short, programs that reproduce the problem.

Here's a short, but complete, program that demonstrates the problem you're having:

```
from random import randrange
class Poly:
    points = [0]*8

    def __init__(self, width=100, height=100):
        for i in range(0, 8, 2):
            self.points[i] = randrange(width)
            self.points[i+1] = randrange(height)
        return

p1 = Poly()
print "p1:", p1.points
p2 = Poly()
print "p2:", p2.points
print "p1:", p1.points
```

Sample output:

```
[C:\Temp] test.py
p1: [19, 5, 1, 46, 93, 18, 18, 57]
p2: [92, 71, 42, 84, 54, 29, 27, 71]
p1: [92, 71, 42, 84, 54, 29, 27, 71]
```

Notice how p1 changed.

The fixed code could be as simple as:

```
from random import randrange
class Poly:
    def __init__(self, width=100, height=100):
        self.points = [0]*8
        for i in range(0, 8, 2):
            self.points[i] = randrange(width)
            self.points[i+1] = randrange(height)
        return
```

although I prefer the append variant that [@Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51305/doug) posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874121/python-list-of-objects-with-random-attributes/874140#874140)

Comment: Thank you. :) Still a Python noob, as you can see.

Comment: Depends. That you're here and asking, willing to lay your code on the line for scrutiny tells me that you might (emphasis on might) be a beginner, but "noob" is a derogatory I would keep for others :)

Comment: Haha, well I'm not a noob/beginner to CS or coding, just to Python.  I'm trying to make the switch from C++, if that wasn't obvious from my mistake.

Comment: And yes, I know C++ and Python have different domains, but they aren't disjoint.

Answer (score 4):

You have a class attribute `Poly.points`. In your `__init__` method you do `self.points[i] = ...`. Now this makes Python use `Poly.points` which is shared by all instances. But you want `points` to be an instance attribute. I'd suggest this:

```
class Poly:
    # you don't need this here
    #points = [0] * 8
    #fill = 'red'
    #alpha = 1.0

    def __init__(self, width=100, height=100):
        self.points = [0]*8
        self.fill = 'red'
        self.alpha = random()
        for i in range(0, 8, 2):
            self.points[i] = randrange(width)
            self.points[i+1] = randrange(height)
```

Answer (score 2):

The points lists are all being shared. It would appear that you're declaring points to be a list on the instance or class. This isn't the way of doing things in Python if you don't want to share the list between instances. Try:

```
def __init__(self, width=100, height=100):
    self.points = [] #Create a new list
    for i in range(0, 8, 2):
        self.points.append(randrange(width))
        self.points.append(randrange(height))
    return
```

Answer (score -1):

ok here is the culprit

points = [[0]] * 8

it assigns same list ([0]) 8 times instead you should do something like

```
points = []
for i in range(8):
    points.append([])
```

Comment: sorry I missed  the inner list, I was telly a way how this may be happening, till that time poly code wasn't there

Comment: uh? where did you take [0] * 8 from then? anyway, you're suggesting a wrong thing to do.